# Create INSERT with ID AUTO_INCREMENT and get that ID to update another table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to create a football team in the table `equipo` where I will insert `ID` `auto_increment`, `nombre`, `descripcion`.

I need to obtain that ID so that the players are inserted in the table `jugadores` from another query (or not necessarily). And I need everything done almost at the same time.

Any solution?

I know that `lastInsertId` gets me the last ID of the last updated table, whatever it is, so it is very possible not to get the ID I need if there is a massive upload of records.

I hope the output is

```
ID      |    NOMBRE   |    DESC
-------------------------------
1001    |    myname    |   blabla

ID   |  ID_EQUIPO  |   NOMBRE
-------------------------------
1    |  1001       |   Jugador
```

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id): "The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a ***per-connection basis***." That means that inserts from other connections (other users) don't affect the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: We can invoke the MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID()` *immediately* following the `INSERT`, before we do anything else with the connection.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: What's your question? You said you know you can use `lastInsertId()` for this, so what problem are you having with using it?

Comment: You're right, you can't do this if you insert multiple rows into the first table. You have to alternate: Add 1 row to the `team` table, put `lastInsertId` into a variable, then add all the rows for that team to the `player` table; repeat this for each team.

Comment: ... @spencer7593 LAST_INSERT_ID() is a SQL function, maybe...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution has finally been this:

```
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO '.self::TABLA.' (nombre_equipo) VALUES (:nombre_equipo)');     
    $consulta->bindParam(':nombre_equipo',  $this->nombre_equipo);        
    $consulta->execute();
    $this->id= $conexion->lastInsertId();
```

Then I use the ID to insert players

Comment: Thanks for de minus Barmar hahah ;)